# Compiling a Haxe library without a Main class

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe

I'm writing a library in Haxe that does not expose a "Main" class.
Instead it simply contains typedefs & classes, which are intended for use
in other applications which are compiled including this library.

If I try to compile without a `-main` option, I get the following error:

```
Haxe Compiler 3.2.1 - (C)2005-2015 Haxe Foundation
 Usage : haxe -main <class> [-swf|-js|-neko|-php|-cpp|-as3] <output> [options]
```

Does the Haxe compiler prevent you from compiling a library that doesn't have an entry point?

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compile without a main using something like the following build.hxml:

```
-cp src 

# add the package(s) that you want to include the following way: 
--macro "include('package1.foo')"
--macro "include('package2.bar.test.buz')"
...

-js bin/index.js
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition, you can setup a dev environment using Haxelib, by using the following command: `haxelib dev libraryName ./` in your projects working directory. If installing it locally, you will need a `haxelib.json` file in your root. Then all you need to then do in your build.hxml file is add the line `-lib libraryName` to tell Haxe where to look for source files.

Comment: @tienery thanks for the comment. I am however, looking for a means to compile locally, and cambiata's macro usage example in the HXML turned out to be exactly what I was after!